# Accidentally Converted Latex into Binary

Tags: texstudio

My `.tex` file, I'm pretty sure has become a binary file. It begins with this:

```
\%PDF-1.5
\%ÐÔÅØ
6 0 obj <<
/Length 1662      
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
```

and there's a lot of odd symbols. I'm using TeXstudio to compile my documents and when I click the 'view' button I get the document as it looked previously so I'm assuming all the data is still there, but is there any way to get this back into a latex form so I can continue actually using it, or do I have to begin from scratch?

Comment: This is your compiled pdf, you can open it with acrobat reader or something similar. Your texfile is somewhere else in the same folder.

Comment: The above is what appears within TeXstudio when I open the `.tex` file.

Comment: I advice you to make a backup before you go on investigating

Comment: open `your-file.tex` with `texstudio` and view `your-file.pdf` with [sumatrapdf after installing it](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html) or [acrobat reader after installing it](http://get.adobe.com/reader/). Guess: You might be opening `your-file.pdf` with text editor or texstudio without having `your-file.tex` inside the same folder

Comment: I'm definitely opening the `.tex` file, and they're in the same folder. Just checked by opening it with TeXworks and it's opened two windows, one with 'Image1.tex' the other with 'Image1.pdf' the `.tex` file is still the compiled pdf file with all the symbols. The pdf window shows my image as it was before this happened.

Comment: Looks like the pdf was somehow renamed as a `.tex` file.  If(!) so, the best thing to do is to revert to a backup version of your `.tex` file.  You cannot travel backwards from `.pdf` to `.tex`.  But you can use the .pdf to capture the bare text if it helps, so don't delete the .pdf until you're sure you're as close to where you were when things went off the rails.

Comment: This is just a wild shot in the dark, but do you have extensions set to view or hide on your OS? If you accidentally do `pdflatex -jobname your-file.tex your-file` you can end up with a file called `your-file.tex.pdf` but with the extension hidden it looks like `your-file.tex`. (Although it does seem more likely that the `.pdf` has been renamed to the `.tex` but what could have done that without your knowledge is a puzzle.)